# Can electric energy be generated from only heat if the heat is uniformly distributed along the system?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation, thermoelectricity

I was thinking about producing energy from heat and I realized that all the methods I know require a heat gradient. Is there a deeper physical explanation as to why heat gradients are *needed*? Otherwise, do you know of any heat to electricity generator that doesn't need a heat gradient?

Comment: Your intuition is correct, but you should do your own research before asking others.

Comment: To add to @safesphere's comment, the key search term is '2nd law of thermodynamics'

Comment: See also [Extracting heat energy without a heat engine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128510) and [Can you extract energy from "hot" things without a temperature differential?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121656)